# How to plot a combined histogram in python?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, histogram, seaborn

I have the following data as example

```
Names   Static  Dynamic
La  0.1 0.7
Li  0.2 0.02
Sa  0.3 0.044
Pa  0.4 0.444
D   0.7 0.1
```

my desire is to draw a combined histogram like this one
[image: Histogram]

any help will be much appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can [`pd.melt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.melt.html) setting `Names` as `id_vars` and use seaborn's [`sns.catplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.catplot.html):

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

sns.catplot(data=(pd.melt(df, id_vars='Names')
                    .rename(columns={'variable':'x-axis', 'value':'y-axis'})),
            x='x-axis', 
            y='y-axis', 
            hue='Names', 
            kind='bar',
            height=6,
            aspect=1.5)
```

[image]

Comment: Fantastic @yatu, Thank you

Comment: i got good results, but i am trying to change the names of the x and y axes it gives me errors

Comment: how to do that?

Comment: Updated @christina

Comment: Thank you a lot @yatu, Very useful answer